# Python - Downloading Federal Reserve Routing Numbers

Tags: python, request

I am new to Python and am struggling with downloading a .txt file from the FederalReserve Website with a list of routing numbers (ACH) and their corresponding financial Institution name.

The biggest caveat is that I have to click on an "Accept" button prior to reaching the page containing the .txt data needed.  Both links to Agreement button and the page containing the .txt data are in my code.  I couldn't list both links because Im too new on this site.

Can anyone please help me?

I've tried multiple approaches including selenium, beautiful soap, TamperData in Firefox to understand what to post back, etc.

Here is what I think should be the simplest route, based on my basic knowledge, but extensive trial and error attempts:

```
import webbrowser
import requests

url = 'https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html'
payload = {'agreementValue':'Agree'}

response = requests.get(url, data=payload)
webbrowser.open("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt")
```

Comment: I can download .csv and .txt files from other sites without issues to a specific location on a hard drive... my main issue here is I can't get passed the page to Accept (click on the Accept button) terms, before proceeding to downloading the .txt data.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few attempts using `requests` and `requests.Session()` with no luck, then simplified things by moving to [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/) and still couldn't manage to get through.

I then switched approach, and the [Mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library came to the rescue.

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open( 'https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/fpddir.txt' )
br.select_form( name="acceptedForm" )
rs = br.submit( name="agreementValue", nr=0 )
print( rs.get_data() )
```

> 011000015FRB-BOS           FEDERAL RESERVE BANK OF BOSTON      MABOSTON                   Y Y20040910
>
> ...

.

---

It's mostly straight-forward code, but this line is the one that matters:

```
rs = br.submit( name="agreementValue", nr=0 )
```

The form has two submit buttons, one *Agree* and another *Do Not Agree* but they both have the same name `name="agreementValue"`. The `nr=0` parameter chooses the first match and submits that one.

Once the submit is made, the remote site automatically loads the desired text file and can be read from the response `rs.get_data()`